# Draw graticule lines using GTM 6 without drawing a border (frame) around the map

Tags: gmt

I'm using Generic Mapping Tool (version 6.4.0 on macOS) to create globe maps. Here's the command I'm using:

```
gmt begin globe png
gmt set MAP_GRID_PEN_PRIMARY 0.04p,140/140/180
gmt coast -Rd -S200/200/240 -JG0/30/6c -Dl -G230/230/230 -Bg
gmt end
```

You can see the map I've got below. As you can see, I'm able to control the appearance of the graticule by setting `MAP_GRID_PEN_PRIMARY`, but I can't set (or better: completely) remove the thick black border around the globe. I've already toyed around with `MAP_GRID_PEN_SECONDARY` or the various options to manipulate the frame using another `-B` option, but that thick black border stays.

If I omit the `-Bg` option completely, the border is gone, but I need the graticule lines.

[image]

Comment: Of course, right after asking the question, I found that `MAP_FRAME_PEN` controls this border. Using something like `gmt set MAP_FRAME_PEN 0.1p,255/255/255` creates a very small border using the background color, so it's nearly not visible and good enough for me right now. But it's not a real answer to my question as the border still gets drawn.